# Why is this JLabel's ImageIcon not updating?

Tags: java, image, swing, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

SSCCE, as small as I could get it with keeping all the logic in the same order:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    BufferedImage img = null; // <-- needs this scope
    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
    JLabel mainImage = new JLabel();

    public Test() {
        mainWindow.add(mainImage);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
// step 5
        mainImage.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                dostuff();
            }
            @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        });
        dostuff();
    }

    private void dostuff() {
// step 1
        try {
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            img = ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            System.exit(1);
        }
//step 2
        mainImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(new Color(0xFFFF0000));
        g.drawOval(10, 10, 10, 10);
        try{Thread.sleep(2000);}catch(Exception e){}
// step 3
        BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(400,300,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int i = 10 ; i < 20 ; i++) {
            for (int j = 10 ; j < 20 ; j++) {
                img2.setRGB(i,j,0xFF0000FF);
            }
        }
// step 4
        mainImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));
        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

}
```

It should be obvious what I'm trying to do, and compiling will show that it's not doing that.  But I want this post to have a question mark so here is the problem description and  question:

What I want to happen:

1. The program loads, and the user is prompted to select a file (an image).
2. Upon a selecting an image, that image is displayed in a JFrame, and some Graphics2D drawings happen on it.  (I included the sleep() because these drawings take a while in the actual program)
3. When the drawings are finished, a new image is created and it is also drawn on.
4. The new image replaces the old image in the JFrame
5. When the user clicks on the image, they are prompted to select a new image, and we repeat from step 1.

What is happening:

Steps one through four work fine.  On step five, after selecting an image, the JFrame is populated by a black rectangle the size of the user-selected image, with the image from step three overlayed in the top left corner, step two does not happen, and steps three through five appear to work just fine.

What's more, in my actual program, I can tell that the new user-selected-image is doing its job just fine by the output that step three produces.

So the question is, how can I fix later repetitions of step two such that the appropriate image is shown in the JFrame?

EDIT: This imgur album shows step by step the results I am getting.
http://imgur.com/a/xW051

EDIT2: updated without Thread.sleep()

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    BufferedImage img = null; // <-- needs this scope
    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
    JLabel mainImage = new JLabel();

    public Test() {
        mainWindow.add(mainImage);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
// step 5
        mainImage.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                dostuff();
            }
            @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        });
        dostuff();
    }

    private void dostuff() {
// step 1
        try {
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            img = ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            System.exit(1);
        }
//step 2
        mainImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(new Color(0xFFFF0000));
        for (int h = 0 ; h < 0xFF ; h++) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < img.getWidth() ; i++) {
                for (int j = 0 ; j < img.getHeight()/2 ; j++) {
                    img.setRGB(i,j,0x88FF0000 + h);
                }
            }
            mainImage.repaint();
        }
// step 3
        BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(400,300,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int i = 10 ; i < 20 ; i++) {
            for (int j = 10 ; j < 20 ; j++) {
                img2.setRGB(i,j,0xFF0000FF);
            }
        }
// step 4
        mainImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));
        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried every combination of repainting, revalidating, and flushing components I could think of, and i have not stumbled on the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

> If I then load a 1000x1000 image, I see a 1000x1000 black square...

I would guess the black images are because you are causing the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) to sleep. so although the frame is resizing with the pack() statement the newly loaded image is not being painted.

Don't use Thread.sleep() in code that is executing on the EDT. All code executed from a listener executes on the EDT. Instead you should be using a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the event to update the image of the label.

Edit 2:

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). In general all event code executes on the EDT. When the EDT is blocked, Swing components can't be repainted.

```
  mainImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
```

The above statement will cause repaint() to be invoked on the "mainImage" label. The repaint() request is passed to the RepaintManager and a painting request is added to the end of the EDT.

So the label will be painted AFTER all the code in the "doStuff()" method has finished executing.

However you also invoke

```
 mainImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));
```

at the end of the method. So by the time the image actually gets painted its Icon has been changed a second time so only the second Icon is painted.

In between those two statements, after reading the image the frame is resized when the pack() method is invoked. I believe this is because the packing of the frame results in OS level painting since a frame is an OS widget not a Swing component. In other words the frame can be resized even if the components on the frame are not repainted.

If you want a responsive GUI then you can't execute long running code on the EDT. In the case of the second SSCCE the "for loop" you added takes a long time 
to run which is effectively blocking the EDT and preventing the newly read Icon from being painted.

Therefore long running tasks should be executed on a separate `Thread`. The concurrency tutorial will explain how you can use a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.

Comment: What you are saying is not correct.  If I load a 400x400 image, I see a 400x400 image.  After 2 seconds, I see the 400x300 generated image.  If I then load a 1000x1000 image, I see a 1000x1000 black square with my 400x300 generated image overlayed in the top left, and 2 seconds later another 400x300 image.  Please run the example code.

Comment: Additionally, I can't see any scenario where ScreenImage would be useful here.

Comment: I have edited the original question with an example gallery showing exactly what i am describing above.

Comment: @user1279343, maybe I don't understand the requirements. See edit.

Comment: The sleep() call just emulates a visible pause from the real program.  Eliminating the call to sleep() does not change the behavior of the program except to eliminate the delay (and thereby hide the problem).

Comment: I have no desire to save the altered image;  the generated image is (in the real program) generated based on alterations to the loaded image.  This is working fine.  Even when i can't see the loaded image, the manipulations and generated image are doing exactly what they're meant to.  The only thing that IS NOT working, is that I can't see the loaded image the 2nd, 3rd, 4th time around.

Comment: Or, to paraphrase my original question "how do I display a newly loaded image in a JLabel that's already displaying an image?"

Comment: @user1279343, there is no special trick to change the Icon of a JLabel, you just use the `setIcon(...)` method. I believe the problem is the posted SSCCE is the Thread.sleep(). Use the Swing Timer.

Comment: I have updated the example (in EDIT2) to not use sleep, and have instead simulated the delay another way.  The exact same problem persists.

Comment: @user1279343, still don't really understand your work flow. You can't really have two `setIcon()` statements in the same method and expect to see both Icons displayed. The only way to do this is to display the first Icon and then start a Timer to display the second Icon. So I can't give a concrete solution only an explanation for the problem. Anyway, see my second edit for more information about the EDT and why the label can't be repainted when you block the EDT.

Comment: I give up.  I can only assume you never ran the example code.  repaint() is called explicity in dostuff() and very evidently works, even though "long running tasks" are executing.  Running the example, (EDIT2), the image is loaded, the "long running tasks" execute, repainting at every iteration, and then seconds later when the "long running tasks" complete, the second image is shown.  All of this works perfectly.  The only thing that isn't working is that subsequent calls to dostuff() do NOT show the selected image.

Comment: To clarify, you're explaining why it shouldn't work.  But I'm trying to tell you it DOES work.  Perfectly.  Exactly once.  I want to understand why subsequent calls aren't working.

Comment: `I want to understand why subsequent calls aren't working.` and I already told you. You have a long running task executing on the EDT that is preventing the GUI from repainting itself in a timely fashion. `it DOES work. Perfectly. Exactly once` - because code executed from the main() method does NOT execute on the EDT and therefore the long running task is NOT preventing the GUI from repainting itself. I have already suggested long running tasks need to be executed on a separate Thread and suggested you might be able to use a SwingWorker. Read the `Concurrency` tutorial!!!

Comment: Wrap the "doStuff()" method from the main() method in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` and the code won't work the first time either. By the way all Swing components should be created and updated on the EDT so your current logic for creating the GUI is incorrect. This is explained in the tutorial.

Comment: Okay, now I understand.  I've accepted your answer, but I would really very strongly suggest you edit it to make it clear that what you're trying to say is "The first call is not run on the EDT, but subsequent calls are, and that is why they aren't working as expected."  And to remove all that stuff about ScreenImage.  Thanks for being patient with me, a courtesy I apparently refused to afford to you.